# How to get the relative path of files in a SourceDirectorySet

Tags: gradle, plantuml

I want to process some sources from a directory structure using a [`SourceDirectorySet`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html) and I'd like to save the output under the build dir, mimicking the original dir structure. E.g.:

```
src / main / plantuml
                + dir1
                   + dir11
                       + file.pu
```

Should result in:

```
build / doc / plantuml
                + dir1
                   + dir11
                       + file.png
```

How could I achieve it?

N.B.: `SourceDirectorySet` is [`PatternFilterable`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/util/PatternFilterable.html)

#### Background

I want to extend janvolck's plugin ["gradle-plantuml-plugin"](https://github.com/janvolck/gradle-plantuml-plugin) (there is already a [corresponding feature request](https://github.com/janvolck/gradle-plantuml-plugin/issues/7)), so that it generates its output files under a configured directory but maintaining the original directory hierarchy. The current implementation of the gradle plugin traverses all files of a `SourceDirectorySet` and generates the output files in the same directory where the source files live.

This is the closest I could come out with:

```gradle
// Process directory trees
mySourceDirectorySet.srcDirTrees.each { DirectoryTree d ->
    project.logger.debug("Processing srcDirTree " + d.dir
        + "; patterns.excludes: " + d.patterns.excludes
        + "; patterns.includes" + d.patterns.includes)

    // Reconstruct a FileTree from the directory tree, as I cannot find
    // any means to get the files directly from 'd' (1)
    // ... and traverse its files
    project.fileTree(dir: d.dir,
        excludes: d.patterns.excludes,
        includes: d.patterns.includes).each { File f ->
            project.logger.info("-- Input file: " + f)

            def relPath = d.dir.toURI().relativize(f.parentFile.toURI())
            def outputPath = "/myOutputDir/" + relPath

            option.setOutputDir(project.file(outputPath))
            processFile(f, option);
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, the trick in `(1)` doesn't seem to work and I cannot recreate an appropriate FileTree.

My untrained gradle intuition says it should be easy to achieve this task. I'm surely missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the plugin, but as I understand your requirement: For every file in your sourceRoot directory, you want to generate a similarly named file in destRoot , while maintaining the directory structure.

Give this a try:

```gradle
def File sourceRoot = new File("src/main/plantuml")
def File destRoot = new File("build/doc/plantuml")

sourceRoot.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { File file ->
    def relPath = sourceRoot.toURI().relativize(file.toURI())
    def destFile = new File(destRoot, relPath.toString())
    destFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
    destFile.createNewFile() //alternatively use this path to create your png
}
```

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings: I'm not the author of the plugin. I just wanted to implement an [enhancement](https://github.com/janvolck/gradle-plantuml-plugin/issues/7)

Comment: Thanks for your try, but '_For every file in your sourceRoot directory, you want to generate a similarly named file in destRoot_' is not exactly what I want. I'm trying to generate a file, not for _every file in sourceRoot_, but for every file in a DirectorySourceSet under the SourceSet `main`. Notice that a DirectorySourceSet could have many directories. I'd like to bring the plugin a bit more in-line with the gradle spirit, in that sources are defined with DirectorySourceSets. Ideally, I would extend the SourceSet with a `plantUML` property, but this would be a different patch.

Comment: so why not run my snippet for every directory in `DirectorySourceSet` and instead of `.createNewFile` run the plugin's `process()` on the child files ? I've done the missing part of recreating the directory structure.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion. I'd rather not because it would ignore possible configured filters: `DirectorySourceSet` is [`PatternFilterable`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/util/PatternFilterable.html)